# ios9.2&xcode7.3 metal debug fail

Tags: metal, xcode7.3, ios9.2

I'm using xcode7.3 to debug metal gpu frames, but the capture gpu frame button is always gray and not available when debugging ios9.2 devices while it's ok with ios9.3 devices. The info shows that "the gpu debugging service is not available on this device(256)". Any solution?

Comment: I suggest you [report a bug](https://bugreport.apple.com/) for this issue.

Comment: Just restart the device and Xcode (sure you did already). I had exactly the same info immediately after adding a new, clean iPhone 7+ to Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

Go to instruments and launch any instrument which collect data from GPU on a remote device, for example, "Metal System trace". Run your program in the instrument, stop it, and then exit an instrument. Start debugging your program in XCode, you should noice that "frame capture" is enables.